Angular - Routes aren't working - Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment
Sorry for my bad english :/
I'm trying to build a simple online shop app with Angular, but so far when I try to access the two routes (home and 'carrinho' [portuguese for cart]) it gives me the error 'Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment' and the browser redirects to localhost:4200 and not to the route I desire. The localhost:4200/carrinho should show the 'carrinho works!' sentence just to be sure thats working, but instead I have the error and redirects me to localhost:4200, same for home. So, any of these two are working.
I'm facing bad things these days, so my attention may have ignored something, I tried to find whatever could be wrong and fix it, even visiting several Stack Overflow Threads here, but couldn't.
app-routing-module.ts - (src/app) folder
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CarrinhoComponent } from './pages/carrinho/carrinho.component'
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'carrinho',
    component: CarrinhoComponent,
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}


app-module.ts - (src/app) folder
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';
import { ProductsHeaderComponent } from './pages/home/components/products-header/products-header.component';
import { FiltersComponent } from './pages/home/components/filters/filters.component';
import { CarrinhoComponent } from './pages/carrinho/carrinho.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    ProductsHeaderComponent,
    FiltersComponent,
    CarrinhoComponent,
  ],

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatGridListModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }


home-component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { ProductsHeaderComponent } from './components/products-header/products-header.component';
import { FiltersComponent } from './components/filters/filters.component';
import { ProductBoxComponent } from './components/product-box/product-box.component';

const ROWS_HEIGHT: { [id: number]: number } = { 1: 400, 3: 335, 4: 350 };

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ProductBoxComponent, FiltersComponent, ProductsHeaderComponent, MatSidenavModule, MatGridListModule],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrl: './home.component.css'
})
export class HomeComponent {
  cols = 3;

  rowHeight = ROWS_HEIGHT[this.cols];

  categoria: string | undefined;

  constructor(){

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  onColumnsCountChange(numCols: number): void {
    this.cols = numCols;
    this.rowHeight=ROWS_HEIGHT[this.cols];
  }

  onShowCategoria(novaCategoria: string): void {
    this.categoria = novaCategoria;
  }
}


app-component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';
import { CarrinhoComponent } from './pages/carrinho/carrinho.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [HomeComponent, HeaderComponent, CarrinhoComponent, RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'loja';
}


app-component.html

      <app-header></app-header>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      <app-home></app-home>


header-component.html (with a button using routerLink for carrinho (cart) route)
<mat-toolbar class="mat-toolbar-custom max-w-7x1-mx-auto border-x justify-between">
  <a routerLink="home">Conheça a Loja</a>
  <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
    <mat-icon
    [matBadge] = "1"
    [style.color]="'rgb(22, 99, 115)'"
    >shopping_cart</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <div class="p-3 divide-y divide-solid">
      <div class="pb-3 flex justify-between">
      <span class="mr-16">1 items</span>
      <br>
      <a routerLink="carrinho">Consultar Carrinho</a>
    </div>
    <div class="p-4">
      <div class="flex justify-between font-light mb2">
      Keyboard x1
      <span class="font-bold">{{ '150' | currency: 'BRL' }}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-between font-light mb2">
        Keyboard x1
        <span class="font-bold">{{ '150' | currency: 'BRL' }}</span>
      </div>
      <div class ="flex justify-between py-3 font-light">
        Total:
        <span class="font-bold">{{ '300' | currency: 'BRL'}}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="pt-3 flex justify-between">
        <button class="bg-text-white-rounded-full w-10 h-10">
          <mat-icon>remove_shopping_cart</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <button routerLink="carrinho" class="bg-text-white-rounded-full w-10 h-10">
          <mat-icon>remove_shopping_cart</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </mat-menu>
</mat-toolbar>


carrinho.component.html
<p>carrinho works!</p>

I expected to actually redirect to localhost:4200/home (showing what's inside the home-component) and localhost:4200/carrinho (showing what's inside the carrinho-component, which's 'carrinho works' just for test purposes).
Update: Just added the /home in index.html and now the home route works, but carrinho stays not working :(
Update2: I added the routes also in the app-routes.ts and it seems like /carrinho is now working, but is loading the components of the home page as well, and not only the ones from carrinho route, so not displaying correctly. Same for the home page..  (this page was right before like in picture 2 without the 'carrinho works')
https://i.sstatic.net/4jFcW.png
https://i.sstatic.net/VLtoZ.png
https://i.sstatic.net/rGDKx.png


Solved: Finally solved the problem with the route carrinho loading components from other routes using the changeDetectionStrategy Alpine used in his answer!

Could you share your routerLink ?

Of course :), updated the post with the new information. But generally, until now, I only used one routerLink in header-component, for a button and in for the 'Consultar Carrinho' link.
Just saw a vid, and I was doing practically the same logic as him, he just typed the route in the browser and it worked, but not for me :(

You need to change the app.component.html:
  <app-header></app-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <app-home></app-home>

To
  <app-header></app-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

The header contains the routerLink of the component, so it's displayed with router-outlet.
This route config creates a static link to the route:
// app-header
<a routerLink="/home">Home component </a>
<a routerLink="/carrinho">Carrinho component</a>

// route configuration
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'carrinho',
    component: CarrinhoComponent,
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

Stackblitz Demo
Note:

If the first segment begins with /, the router looks up the route from the root of the app.
If the first segment begins with ./, or doesn't begin with a slash, the router looks in the children of the current activated route.
If the first segment begins with ../, the router goes up one level in the route tree.


Thanks for your attention.
So If I type localhost:4200/home or carrinho in the browser, in order to actually match the routes, I need to add the slash in the routerLinks in header-component?
Tried this but still doesn't work. No matter the changes I make in the routerlinks, the URL still don't match, and doesn't redirect to them :(

you have a  tag in the index.html ?

Yes try with slash like: Conheça a Loja

Added the  for home in index.html and now the route home works! Thanks, but carrinho stays the same :(

you have put slash for Consultar Carrinho

Did it, but still don't work ;(

Hey Alpine, had some updates, edited the main post..
carrinho seems like to match but isn't displaying correctly, same for home now

@IgorC I don’t understand why you need to add  the /home in index.html ?  Could you please share the current index.html ?

Your snapshot are not displayed .

Cannot upload images here yet :/ But I think copy and paste in the URL bar will work, if there's any other way I could send it here..
But generally, iwhen I access the route carrinho it loads both components of home and carrinho.
And home seems to be displayed incorrectly (buttons out of place, icons doesn't apepar on the screen, rather writings appears instead)

I fixed the problem with the icons and buttons. But the problem with carrinho route loading the components of home stays the same :(

@IgorC check stackblitz demo

Thank you so much Alpine! What worked for me is to add changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush on the header.component.html, and now the route carrinho only shows the 'carrinho works'. I hope I won't need to bother with any more questions until I finish this little project xD. Thanks for your attention!
